# Extract Comma separated Values from String

Tags: java, for-loop, indexof

I'm trying to print comma separated value from below string

```
A,B,C,D,E
```

Here is my Code

```
String Inp = "A,B,C,D,E";
StringBuilder op = new StringBuilder();
int Idx = 0;
int IdxUpto = 0;
for(;;){
  IdxUpto = Inp.indexOf(",", Idx);
  if(IdxUpto==-1){
    System.out.println("There is no more commas in String");
    op.append(Inp.substring(Idx, Inp.length()));
    System.out.println(op);
    break;
  }
  op.append(Inp.substring(Idx, IdxUpto));
  Idx = IdxUpto;
  System.out.println(op);
}
```

For loop is not getting stop after first extraction, Can anyone please help what am doing WRONG ?

Edit:

Expected Output

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual output you want to see here?

Comment: I think this is going to keep finding the same comma since you keep pointing to the first one found. Try `Idx = IdxUpto + 1;` instead of `Idx = IdxUpto;`.

Comment: If you just want to print the values then you should should use the split method of the string class and iterate over the returned array. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: Why can't you use `String.split(",")`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Question Updated..! Please check..!

Comment: Looks like both answers so far pointed out what I already said in my comment. ;) Also, your `op.append(Inp.substring(Idx, IdxUpto));` will, of course, keep appending (that's what `append` does) and not give you the result you say you want. You just need to print `Inp.substring(Idx, IdxUpto)` each time. You don't need to append anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the offending line in your code:

```
Idx = IdxUpto;
```

You should be incrementing plus one, to take into account that you have to also advance past the comma delimiter, which has a width of one.  So use this:

```
Idx = IdxUpto + 1;
```

But note that you have several other problems.  For one thing, you should be following Java conventions and avoid starting your variable names with capital letters.  Also, it probably makes more sense to use a `while` loop here rather than a `for` loop with no criteria specified.  Taking all this into account, here is a working version of your script:

```
String input = "A,B,C,D,E";
StringBuilder op = new StringBuilder();
int idx = 0;
int idxUpto = 0;
do {
    idxUpto = input.indexOf(",", idx);
    if (idxUpto == -1) {
        String term = input.substring(idx, input.length());
        op.append(term);
        System.out.println(term);
        System.out.println("There is no more commas in String");
        break;
    }
    String term = input.substring(idx, idxUpto);
    op.append(term);
    idx = idxUpto+1;
    System.out.println(term);
} while(true);

A
B
C
D
E
There is no more commas in String
```

Answer (score 0):

String's `indexof` api says as below:

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index.

When you enter your for condition, you get index as 1 (index place where you find first comma). Now what you do is set Idx to this index as below:

```
Idx = IdxUpto;
```

Now since index of api starts the search for comma from that index, it keeps on saying i found at index 1 and you keep on trying to search for comma at index 1. To fix the problem, try to add one like below:

```
Idx = IdxUpto + 1;
```

Couple of things to note:

a. Use camel case variable naming conventions.
b. You are appending to StringBuilder, if you need desired output as expected, then your `println` statement should change as:

```
System.out.println(Inp.substring(Idx, IdxUpto));//mutate Idx assignment after this print statement.
```

Comment: Once I've found A in my Code, then my Idx and IdxUpto both would be 1, then why am getting keep printed A ?

Comment: @Trisha, because as this answer points out, as well as my prior comments to your original post indicate, your `Idx = IdxUpto;` causes `A` to continually to be printed. You need `Idx = IdxUpto + 1;` instead. With `Idx = IdxUpto;` you point to the same first comma over and over again in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `String.split()` method like this:

```
public class StringSplit {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "A,B,C,D,E";
    String[] array = input.split(",");
    for (String letter : array) {
      System.out.println(letter);
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

A
B
C
D
E

Comment: Of course this is the best answer, but my guess is that the OP is doing some kind of assignment where `String#split` is not allowed :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, That's what I initially thought as well. But then, if you can use `indexOf()` and `substring()`, then why not `split()`. :)